# Jquery load() puts display and opacity in element style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an html that, by AJAX, fetches data from a php file and shows a table with the content ofthe database.

In another file, I try to call load(initial.html) to a div and the code shows up fine, but when I hit the button to retrieve the table, the element style of the div where the tabçe will be written shows up automatically "display: none; opacity: 0". And than in that table I have a tablesorter and it doesn't work.

But if I enter the original page all works, but I can't put it work if I load the html to another file.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks very much

EDIT:

I tried other way, but now the ("#teste").on('submit') doesn't work.
and if I put the code in the main page and forget the load() it works fine. Why is that?

Thank you for the help

Here is the code:

the main page, when o click link_1 I call load() to populate the div id="principal"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Teste </title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/procura.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.blue.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/procura.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div id="banner-image">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="banner-content">
            <a id="link_1" href="">Procurar Colaborador</a>
            <a id="link_2" href="">Confirmação de Colaboradores</a>
        </div>

        <div id="principal">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Html that I call called procura.html

```
<form action="" id="teste" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="itemRows">
        <p>
            <select name="tipo_procura[]" >
                <option value="" selected></option>
                <option value="loja_integracao">Loja de Integração</option>
                <option value="nome_completo">Nome</option>
            </select>
            <input name="valor_procura[]" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" />
            <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" class="form_button" type="button" value="Adicionar Procura" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Procurar" />
</form>
<div class="result" id="result">

</div>
```

THE JS file procura.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    $("#link_1").click(function(event) {
        $("#principal").load("procura.html");
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#teste').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            url : 'procura_colaborador.php',
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#result").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).html(data);
                }).fadeIn("slow");

            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();

    });

});

var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><select name="tipo_procura[]" ><option value="" selected></option><option value="loja_integracao">Loja de Integração</option><option value="nome_completo">Nome</option></select><input name="valor_procura[]" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" /><input type="button" value="Remover Procura" class="form_button" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
}
```

And the PHP file

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM colaboradores";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

echo '<table id="tabela_resultados" class="tablesorter-blue">';
echo '<thead><tr><th>Loja de Integração</th><th>Nome</th><th>Telemóvel</th><th>NIF</th><th>Data de Nascimento<th>Nacionalidade</th><th>Acção</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

while ($gear = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $gear['loja_integracao'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $gear['nome_completo'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $gear['num_tlm'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $gear['num_nif'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $gear['data_nascimento'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $gear['nacionalidade'];
    echo "</td><td><a href=''>Contrato</a></td></tr>";

}


echo '</tbody></table>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#tabela_resultados").tablesorter();</script>';
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Here it is, with a few changes, but not working. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly
try to change your json function to retrive html data , because you cant't retrive json when you 
do echo in php file if you want to retrive your table you must add to json function , `dataType: "html"`

```
 $('#teste').on('submit', function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'procura_colaborador.php',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#result").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).html(data);
            }).fadeIn("slow");

        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

Comment: yes thank you. I realized that and change it, and a lot more stuff. To be more efficient.